# Django get image from ModelForm

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a model containing an ImageField like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField()
```

and a form like:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['photo',]
```

and the in my view:

```
def show_form(request):
    form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None)
    content = {
        'form': form,
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        mymodel = form.save(commit=False)
        mymodel.save()

    return render(request, 'appname/template.html', content)
```

and my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <table align="center">
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

but whenever I choose a picture and click submit the form tells me that this field is required and it is not saving it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide and `upload_to` parameter in the `ImageField`

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

and make the form like this

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and make sure you have `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` defined

and change your view to this

```
def show_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None)
       if form.is_valid():
          mymodel = form.save(commit=False)
          mymodel.save()
    else:
       content = {
        'form': form,
        }
       return render(request, 'appname/template.html', content)
```

Comment: sadly still the same error and I didn't forget to migrate

Comment: have you declared MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings file

Comment: yes, `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` and `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`